# What's going on? PhpStorm 10.0.1 and Angular

Tags: angular, phpstorm

**Error**

> :Cannot start compiler process:  Error: Parse tsconfig error
>   [{"messageText":"Unknown compiler option
>   'baseUrl'.","category":1,"code":5023},{"messageText":"Argument for
>   '--module' option must be 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system' or
>   'umd'.","category":1,"code":6046},{"messageText":"Unknown compiler
>   option
>   'importHelpers'.","category":1,"code":5023},{"messageText":"Unknown
>   compiler option
>   'typeRoots'.","category":1,"code":5023},{"messageText":"Unknown
>   compiler option 'lib'.","category":1,"code":5023}]

[image]

Comment: Maybe (just maybe) it's time to upgrade? (v10 is 3 years old) It's possible that TypeScript compiler/Angular is not compatible with your IDE version? Try latest stable 2018.3.x or even an EAP build of 2019.1. **P.S.** if it worked yesterday and you can say for sure that you have not updated anything ... then I do not know why it suddenly broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it seems that typescript version set in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript** is less than `2.0`. You must be using the bundled version (`1.4`), aren't you? You can specify a custom version (by choosing your local `node_modules\typescript\lib` folder), but this won't work either: the typescript compiler service that comes with PhpStorm 10 is not compatible with recent Typescript versions.

If upgrading PhpStorm is not an option for you, I can only suggest disabling the built-in compiler - it won't work for project generated with recent angular cli versions

Comment: thanks -- Why is the project files red? Is this true or is there any mistake?

Comment: must be a version control status color (unversioned)? Check **Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | File Status**